# Laravel Session is not storing new items but it's overwriting

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-session

**I was trying to add new items to a session container, and if old items are available then I'll just push the new items to the container. Now whenever I'm adding new items it's storing the current item by replacing the previous item, where is the issue?**

**In Controller my function to add new items**

```
public function addToCart($id)
{
    $product = Product::findOrFail($id);

    $oldCart = Session::has("cart") ? Session::get("cart") : null;

    $cart = new Cart($oldCart);

    $cart->addNewItem($id, $product);

    Session::put("cart", $cart);

    dd(Session::get("cart"));
}
```

**In Class**

```
class Cart
{
    public $items = null;
    public $totalQty = 0;
    public $totalPrice = 0;

    public function __construct($oldCart)
    {
        if ($oldCart) {
            $this->items = $oldCart->items;
            $this->totalQty = $oldCart->totalQty;
            $this->totalPrice = $oldCart->totalPrice;
        }
    }

    public function addNewItem($id, $item)
    {
        $storeNewItem["product_id"] = $item->id;
        $storeNewItem["product_name"] = $item->product_name;
        $storeNewItem["product_price"] = $item->product_price;

        $this->totalQty++;
        $this->totalPrice += $item->product_price;
        $this->items[$id] = $storeNewItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Laravel Framework 8.83.8

Answer (score 0):

In Cart Class

```
public function addNewItem($id,$item) {
    
    $storeNewItem["product_id"] = $item->id;
    $storeNewItem["product_name"] = $item->product_name;
    $storeNewItem["product_price"] = $item->product_price;

    $this->totalQty++;
    $this->totalPrice += $item->product_price;

    return [
             'totalQty', => $this->totalQty,
             'totalPrice', => $this->totalPrice,
             'items[$id]', => $storeNewItem,
           ]

}
```

In Controller addToCart Function

```
$newCart = $cart->addNewItem($id,$product);

Session::put("cart",$newCart );
```